# factory_girl rspec test failure with before_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I have a newbie question here. I've been following along with the rails tutorial and I've hit a snag in my tests. When I implement the following filter...

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:edit, :update]
```

...all of my user_controller_spec.rb tests related to 'GET edit' and 'PUT update' start to fail where before they passed. Here's one that should have returned true, but returned false:

```
describe "GET 'edit" do

 before(:each) do
   @user = Factory(:user)
   test_sign_in(@user)
 end

 it "should be successful" do
   get :edit, :id => @user
   response.should be_success
 end
end
```

And this is my test_sign_in code in spec_helper.rb

```
def test_sign_in(user)
 controller.sign_in(user)
end
```

The sign_in method is in SessionsHelper, which is incuded in ApplicationController:

```
def sign_in(user)
 cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]
 current_user = user
end
```

I don' know how to further investigate. My guess is that since Rspec was unable to 'GET edit' there must be a log of that request that I can look at, but the test only tells me it returned false. Where can I look next?

Update: What I found in log/test.log is that every 'Processing by UsersController#index as HTML' line is followed by a redirect as follows:

```
  Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
  [1m [35mUser Load (0.2ms) [0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
  Redirected to http://test.host/signin
```

Does this mean that every test index action is followed by a redirect to signin? If this were true it would seem consistent with tests including the test_sign_in method (above) failing and other tests like this one passing:

```
describe "GET 'index' for non-signed-in users" do     
  it "should deny access" do
    get :index
    response.should redirect_to(signin_path)
  end
end
```

I'm going to try to wrap my head around the test_sign_in method again.

Comment: Could you show us the sign_in method?

Comment: Gladly. Thank you, Lichtamberg.

Comment: Try looking at the contents of `log/test/log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `self` in the `sign_in` helper.

```
def sign_in(user)
  cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]
  self.current_user = user
end
```